# Receiving before sending?

Tags: ros, time

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am a ROS noobie, so bare with me.

I've just implemented the "talker.py" and "listener.py" example in the very helpful ROS tutorial pages.

Out of curiosity, I modified my listener.py such that it calls rospy.get_time() as the first step of the callback() function. Then it calculates the difference between this timestamp and the one sent by the talker (now - received time) as a rudimentary way to estimate the time-lag of sending/receiving a message. I then log both this instantaneous difference, the average of the last 100 such measurements and their standard deviation.

Here is a snippet of the resulting output:

```
[INFO] [WallTime: 1455490866.482270] /listener_10101_1455490785467Time diff: 0.00205, avg(100): 0.00116 +/- 0.00029 
[INFO] [WallTime: 1455490866.581423] /listener_10101_1455490785467Time diff: 0.00113, avg(100): 0.00116 +/- 0.00029 
[INFO] [WallTime: 1455490866.681358] /listener_10101_1455490785467Time diff: 0.00111, avg(100): 0.00116 +/- 0.00029 
[INFO] [WallTime: 1455490866.781439] /listener_10101_1455490785467Time diff: 0.00117, avg(100): 0.00116 +/- 0.00029 
[INFO] [WallTime: 1455490866.881240] /listener_10101_1455490785467Time diff: 0.00104, avg(100): 0.00116 +/- 0.00029 
[INFO] [WallTime: 1455490866.981350] /listener_10101_1455490785467Time diff: 0.00102, avg(100): 0.00116 +/- 0.00029
```

I've found that over time the values are occasionally < 0 (see the transition in the second line below), indicating the the time stamp on receipt of the message is BEFORE the time stamp sent by the talker. That is the message is received before it was sent!!! (What???)

```
[INFO] [WallTime: 1455490892.081103] /listener_10101_1455490785467Time diff: 0.00089, avg(100): 0.00105 +/- 0.00015 
[INFO] [WallTime: 1455490892.181117] /listener_10101_1455490785467Time diff: 0.00091, avg(100): 0.00105 +/- 0.00015 
[INFO] [WallTime: 1455490898.958321] /listener_10101_1455490785467Time diff: -0.00189, avg(100): 0.00102 +/- 0.00033 
[INFO] [WallTime: 1455490898.959107] /listener_10101_1455490785467Time diff: -0.00100, avg(100): 0.00100 +/- 0.00039 
[INFO] [WallTime: 1455490892.376509] /listener_10101_1455490785467Time diff: -0.00369, avg(100): 0.00096 +/- 0.00061 
[INFO] [WallTime: 1455490892.477625] /listener_10101_1455490785467Time diff: -0.00259, avg(100): 0.00092 +/- 0.00070
```

I would be thrilled if anyone could help me understand either what conceptual error I am making here or how this is possible?

EDIT: Here is the important part of the code (the callback() function).  (sorry for the mess in the comments below)

```
import numpy as np

valuelist = []

def callback(data, vals = valuelist):
    now = rospy.get_time()
    sentval = data.data.split()
    dt = now - float(sentval[2])
    if vals.__len__() < 100:
        vals.insert(0,dt)
    else:
        vals.pop()
        vals.insert(0,dt)
    
    valsnp = np.array(vals)
    rospy.loginfo(rospy.get_caller_id() + 'Time diff: %0.5f, avg(%3d): %0.5f +/- %0.5f ' % (dt, valsnp.size, valsnp.mean(),valsnp.std()) )
```

EDIT2: The talker code (talker.py)

```
import rospy
from std_msgs.msg import String

def talker():
    pub = rospy.Publisher('chatter', String, queue_size=10)
    rospy.init_node('talker', anonymous=True)
    rate = rospy.Rate(10) # 10hz
    while not rospy.is_shutdown():
        hello_str = "hello world %s" % rospy.get_time()
        pub.publish(hello_str)
        rospy.loginfo(hello_str)
        rate.sleep()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        talker()
    except rospy.ROSInterruptException:
        pass
```

Thanks in advance,
Val

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/226625/receiving-before-sending???/) by [vschmidt](https://answers.ros.org/users/25950/vschmidt/) on ROS Answers with karma: 242 on 2016-02-14

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2016-02-14**:
Are the talker and listener running on the same computer? Sometimes you'll see time travel if the clock on the sender is ahead of the clock on the receiver.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-02-15**:\

> I'm happy to post the code if that's helpful.

If this is running on the same machine then seeing the code would indeed be helpful.

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2016-02-15**:
How is your talker formatting and sending timestamps? It looks like you're doing something complicated with timestamps instead of simply using the `stamp` field in the message header.

**Comment by [vschmidt](https://answers.ros.org/users/25950/vschmidt/) on 2016-02-16**:
It's exactly (indeed the same file) as in the tutorial here: http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/WritingPublisherSubscriber%28python%29

Maybe I should add, although I don't think it should matter, is that this is all running on a virtual machine.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-02-17**:
The wiki page you link shows you how to publish `string`s, not timestamps. Can we assume you are `str(ts)` on the sender side? Any particular reason you're not just using the [msg.header.stamp](http://docs.ros.org/indigo/api/std_msgs/html/msg/Header.html) field?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-02-17**:
Could you please just add the sender side of your code as well?

**Comment by [vschmidt](https://answers.ros.org/users/25950/vschmidt/) on 2016-02-17**:
I've added the talker code. I'm not using the msg.header.stamp field simply because the tutorial didn't. (The tutorial hasn't discussed the header msg yet.)

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-02-17**:
Thank you. I suspect there is some rounding going on, which sometimes makes the received ts being floored, sometimes ceiled, resulting in minute 'jumps' in the deltas.

**Comment by [vschmidt](https://answers.ros.org/users/25950/vschmidt/) on 2016-02-17**:
Ok, I think I've figured out what's going on. This call `rospy.get_time()` only produces time to two decimal places and it seems to be rounding that value. So when the fractional second is say 0.006, this gets reported as 0.01. So the logger can timestamp before 0.01 actually occurs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You are right and you beat me to it. This call

```
rospy.get_time()
```

only produces time to two decimal places and it seems to be rounding that value. So when the fractional second is say 0.006, this gets reported as 0.01. So the logger can timestamp before 0.01 actually occurs.

Thanks for your help with this!!!

---

Originally posted by [vschmidt](https://answers.ros.org/users/25950/vschmidt/) with karma: 242 on 2016-02-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-02-17**:
Just for the record: `rospy.get_time()` just returns a `float` value. The nr decimals is not limited to 2, that really depends on the formatting string used to print it. Calling that function in a Python session in a terminal gets me this fi: `1455714769.854213`.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-02-17**:
You can probably do what you want, by using something like `%.8f` instead of `%s` where you assign your string to `hello_str`.

**Comment by [vschmidt](https://answers.ros.org/users/25950/vschmidt/) on 2016-02-17**:
Ah. thanks!

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2016-02-17**:
I *strongly* recommending using the ROS `time` type (or the `stamp` field in the header, if your message has a header) for transferring times between nodes, instead of trying to convert times to strings and back. Any conversion of a time to a string will lose precision and semantics.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-02-17**:
I'm obviously *not* recommending to start publishing / handling / using timestamps in messages in this way. I was merely trying to explain what was happening, and that there is a way to get Python to stringify a `float` with more decimals than the 2 observed by @vschmidt.